# Redirecting uncertified HTTPS domains to HTTP

Tags: apache-2.2, ssl-certificate

Is there a method for redirecting HTTPS domain without a certificate to one with a certificate in Apache 2 or to HTTP?

If no certificate is found, go to HTTP instead.

Comment: It's the same as any other redirect.

Comment: But how do I check if its not certified? And initiate the redirect base on that fact

Comment: You could check if HTTPS is not enabled with [RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS).

Comment: Is this your server? It doesn't have a certificate if you didn't install one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't have a valid TLS certificate for a server / virtual host, browsers won't connect to it without giving a warning.

A TLS connection must be properly set up before the HTTP redirect message can be sent to the client.

I suggest you get a free Let's Encrypt certificate on your server and use HTTPS.

Comment: I have certificates for all my domains and subdomains. But in the case that someone who thinks www is needed, they might write www.subdomain.example.com and it gives a security warning. I would like to redirect unsecured to anything secure.

Comment: Then you need to have a wild card certificate for all the `*.subdomain.example.com` subdomains.